# error mxnet build inside Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I tried to build mxnet inside a Docker image, I got the following message :

```
Step 14/16 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /workspace/Project/mxnet"]

---> Running in c9337d66ee5e /workspace/Project/mxnet  
Removing intermediate container c9337d66ee5e  
---> b92ad26e0218  Step 15/16 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "make"]  
---> Running in 653a66e430b2 make:
*** No targets specified and no makefile found.  
Stop. The command '/bin/bash -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like there's no Makefile in the working directory inside your container. Can you post your entire `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @sp0gg, i'm sorry I can't since it contain some confidential information
but for more details, the mxnet folder is inside a project which is in the host-machine.
in the dockerfile I have :

WORKDIR /workspace/My_Project
COPY .  .
nextI can a script sh to install some package, and finally I return to the project in order to build mxnet ?

Comment: @sp0gg ; inside my project where I placed the dockerfile too, I run this command line : docker build -t My_image .

Answer (score 0):

The issue at

```
Step 15/16 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "make"] 
[…] The command '/bin/bash -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

probably comes from the fact you run beforehand this command:

```
Step 14/16 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /workspace/Project/mxnet"]
```

which is a typical bug pattern in Docker.

To sum up, each Docker RUN command is run in a subshell, so that if you do

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /workspace/Project/mxnet"]
RUN other commands
```

The other commands won't be affected by the directory change.

To solve this, you can either:

1. replace both lines with

   ```
   RUN cd /workspace/Project/mxnet && other commands
   ```
2. or (solution preferred) replace both lines with

   ```
   WORKDIR /workspace/Project/mxnet
   RUN other commands
   ```

Solution 2 is more idiomatic, and note that

```
WORKDIR /dir
RUN some command
```

can be semantically seen as the equivalent of the command

```
mkdir -p /dir && cd /dir && /bin/sh -c "some command"
```